# Python error because of regex inside a Google Big Query

Tags: python, regex, google-bigquery

I am writing Google Big Query wrappers in python. One of the queries has a regex and the python code is treating it as an syntax error.

Here is the regex 
WHEN tier2 CONTAINS '-' THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT(tier2,'(.*)\s-')

the error is Invalid string literal: '(.*)\s-'>
The error is for \ in the regex.
Any suggestion to overcome it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape backslash by preceding it with yet another backslash
Backslash `\` is an escape character so you need to escape it so it is treated as a normal character

Try

```
'(.*)\\s-'
```

Based on your comments, looks like above is exactly what you are using in BigQuery - so in this case you need to escape each of two backslashes

```
'(.*)\\\\s-'
```

Comment: you are right...the code works in big query with \\ but in python somehow its throwing error.

Comment: This is what i am using in the query .....WHEN tier2 CONTAINS '-' THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT(tier2,'(.*)\\s-')

Comment: so you need escape it twice in this case - try `'(.*)\\\\s-'`

Comment: You are amazing...Mr Berlyant you are brilliant :)