# Google BigQuery SQL query working in Web-UI not returning results in Python / Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, google-bigquery

I have a query in Google BigQuery that is working just fine in the BigQuery Web-UI (which I use for testing) but fails to return any results when run in Python / Pandas.

*BigQuery Web-UI*:

```
SELECT COUNT(foo) AS Foo FROM `dataset.table` WHERE 
REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(title),r'(\b(bar)\b)')
```

*returns*:

```
Row Foo  
1   4087
```

*in Python / Pandas*:

```
import pandas as pd
project_id = 'some_id'
query = """SELECT COUNT(foo) AS Foo FROM `dataset.table` WHERE 
REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(title),r'(\b(bar)\b)')"""

df=pd.read_gbq(query, project_id, dialect='standard')
```

*returns*:

```
print(df)
    Foo
0   0
```

This is by far not the most complex regex query I am using, and so far using the Web-UI to test queries worked like a charm.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

**---EDIT---**

I was able to recreate the issue using the [public Shakespeare dataset](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/bigquery-public-data:samples.shakespeare), which I copied into my existing project as `'sample:shakespeare_copy'` to avoid possible authentication issues.

*GBQ Web-UI*:

```
SELECT COUNT(word_count) AS Foo FROM `bigquery-public- 
data.samples.shakespeare` WHERE 
REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(corpus),r'(\b(sonnets)\b)')
```

*returns*:

```
Row Foo  
1   3677
```

*Python / Pandas*:

```
import pandas as pd
project_id = 'some_id'
query="""SELECT COUNT(word_count) AS Foo FROM sample.shakespeare_copy 
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(LOWER(corpus),r'(\b(sonnets)\b)')"""
df=pd.read_gbq(query,project_id,dialect='standard')
```

*returns*:

```
print(df)
     Foo
0    0
```

When running a query without `REGEXP_CONTAINS()` everything works as intended.

```
query="""SELECT COUNT(word_count) AS Foo FROM sample.shakespeare_copy"""
df=pd.read_gbq(query,projectid,dialect='standard')

print(df)
    Foo
0  164656
```

Many Thanks in advance!
Stephan

Comment: My first guess is that you are reading from the wrong project.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I checked that and also ran some other queries, all them working as intended. I have a strong suspicion that the issue has to do with REGEX_CONTAINS(). I did follow the documentation, though, and all other regex queries work as intended, so I remain puzzled.

Comment: . . My second guess is the back quotes in the regular expression.  Try using a simpler regular expression.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, the back quotes were indeed the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070708/python-error-because-of-regex-inside-a-google-big-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

As per [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070708/python-error-because-of-regex-inside-a-google-big-query) it is necessary to use double backslashes when writing SQLs in Python. Lesson learned. Using `r('\\b(bar)\\b')` gets the desired result.